# Relation between the kernel version and OS version

Tags: ubuntu, kernel

I am running a Ubuntu of version 12.04.
Can I use a kernel of version of version 2.4 on it?

Comment: The kernel version determines several other pieces of software that is intimately related to the kernel. It might work, but I wouldn't count on it. What do you want to do this for?

Comment: Please do not cross-post to multiple SE sites: http://askubuntu.com/questions/268089/kernel-compilation-of-version-2-4-on-a-system-running-3-2-0 cross-post

Comment: Again, what do you want to do with an EOL kernel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a lot of things broken if you would use a kernel 2.4 on it.

First, such an old kernel might not (honestly it will not) recognize some or all your hardware because it did not exist at that time. Depending on the not recognized hardware you might or might not be able to start your machine.

Then, all the user space applications that directly communicate with the kernel might (or will) not work. Because the kernel architecture and feature changed that much that they are no longer compatible with it. Thus again you probably won't be able to boot.

So I would advise not to do it on a used system. If you really want to try it, create a VM, install Ubuntu in it, compile your kernel (if that works still!) and reboot the VM using this kernel. I doubt it will work, but who knows :-)

Comment: Recompiling libc should solve most of the problems, though. My main concern would be security though - 2.4 is not maintained any more.

Comment: @peterph That's a good point :) Regarding the libc, recompiling one that would match a 2.4 kernel with a recent GCC might be a challenge still. Don't you think?

Comment: @Huygens that depends a lot on the libc in question. Building Glibc can easily get difficult on its own, that's true, but I don't think it would be that terrible as both GCC and Glibc strive for reasonable backward compatibility - I would expect it to be tedious but rather straightforward. Haven't tried though. :)

Comment: It's not only `glibc`, other pieces (like `systemd` if you use it) depend on new cgroups functionality, probably stuff like `ps` and `iptables` will depend on it too. Best bet is to unearth an old distribution (there are archived versions of at least Red Hat, Fedora, and old CentOS still to be found).

Comment: @vonbrand fully agree and that is what I called *user space applications* in my answer :)

Comment: @peterph I remember some years ago (2001), I inherited a Linux dev machine at work but I quickly figured out that no package manager where installed, neither GCC. Finding a binary GCC that would work for that machine libc proved a dead end. We tried compiling a GCC for the libc I had on another machine (which had a different software stack), but after too much lost time, we just re-installed my machine. There was some big changes between GCC 2.97.3 and 2.98 unfortunately.

Comment: @Huygens well, garbage in - garbage out. Once you have a broken system, getting it to work (or even work well) is [WOMBAT](http://www.acronymfinder.com/WOMBAT.html). If the libc there was built in a non-standard manner (which it likely was), integrating it with anything would have been be difficult.